# Integration prove question

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a prove question, I can't figure out how to do it, can anyone please help me? I would really appreciate it!

[image: http://puu.sh/1ZYIB]

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the Integral of $\int\_a^bf(x)~dx~~=\int\_a^bf(a+b-x)~dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166553/how-is-the-integral-of-int-abfxdx-int-abfab-xdx) This is a strict subset of the question, I have answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166553/how-is-the-integral-of-int-abfxdx-int-abfab-xdx/166571#166571).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Prove:
$$\int_0^a f(x)\;dx=\int_0^a f(a-x)\;dx\\$$
Proof:

\begin{align}
RHS&=\int_0^a f(a-x)\;dx\\
y&=a-x\\dy&=-dx\\\int_0^a&\rightarrow\int_a^0\\
&\int_a^0f(y)\times-1\;dy\\&=\int_0^af(y)\;dy\\&=\int_0^af(x)dx
\end{align}